# ng-if not found or not working outside ng-view

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

For sample: please check the link http://plnkr.co/edit/Q3Z669FeRHqMORcQ9v6K?p=preview.

I am working in Visual studio 2013.

I am trying to hide or based on authentication, I want to show the menu. But ng-if not working outside the ng-view.

Actually ng-if is not coming with the intellisense. Though I pasted the code, I didn't get. **But ng-hide is working**.

I am getting the ng-hide. But I don't like to use ng-hide, because this will just hide the element. So using inspect element, we can enable the menu.

Why I am not getting ng-if? Am I doing in the wrong way

```
 <div id="page-wrapper" ng-controller="indexController">
        <div id="page-header" class="bg-gradient-9" ng-if="!authentication.isAuth">
            <div id="mobile-navigation">
                <button id="nav-toggle" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#page-sidebar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"><span></span></button>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="logo-content-small" title=" {{ '' | translate }}"></a>
            </div>
            <!--Logo for all the screen-->
            <div id="mobile-navigation">
                <a href="#/" class="logo-content-small" title=""></a>
            </div>
            <div id="header-logo" class="logo-bg mobile-hidden">
                <a href="#/" class="logo-content-big" title="">

                </a>
                <a href="#/" class="logo-content-small" title="NoteReport">
                    NoteReport
                </a>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div id="page-content-wrapper ">
            <!--Partial loading of the content-->
            <div class="angular-ngview-content" ng-view>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what is `!authentication.isAuth`?

Comment: I guess you checking the condition wrong. ng-if will show the content only if the evaluated expression executes to true value. Are you sure your are getting false in "authentication.isAuth" . I mean if authentication.isAuth = false some where in your "indexController" only then will it show the div block

Comment: Yes I am sure. Actually ng-hide is working.

Comment: Suggest you create a demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) that replicates issue. We can't see your controllers to do any debugging

Comment: Yes, I've done. Can you please check the updated question or the following link? http://plnkr.co/edit/Q3Z669FeRHqMORcQ9v6K?p=preview

Comment: A working plunk would be more helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the ancient old issue if child scopes created by `ng-if`, try:

`ng-if="!$parent.authentication.isAuth"`

**EDIT**

The `ng-if` directive was provided after angular 1.1.5, you are using 1.0.5. [Working plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/cb3H6gVhxlhLUv03pbTP?p=preview).

Comment: sorry, I think this is not a solution for this. I've tried it's not working. Actually ng-hide="!authentication.isAuth" is working.

Comment: @JeevaJsb Is ng-show="!authentication.isAuth" working?

Comment: Obviously, if ng-hide is working, then ng-show=="authentication.isAuth" should work. Yes ng-show working.

Comment: Well i was asking because i wanted to make sure that maybe the html wasn't rendering due to the statement evaluating to false. I don't know, my guess would be the child scoping issue :)

Comment: Please Check my updated question ? I've added plunkr. Actually ng-hide is working. i don't know why ng-if is not working.

Comment: Thanks :-) .. It's working. But there is slow performance for large page.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of ng-if creating a child scope and how prototypical inheritance works with primitives.just check once like

```
 ng-if="authentication.isAuth"
```

change angularjs version to 1.3.8...It will work

Comment: No it doesn't work. Can you check my updated question? I've done sample with this. Actually ng-hide is working. You can check there.